# Adding new Dataframe column for every Excel file with Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

i got a folder with multiple excel files which i want to concatenate to a new excel file.

The files are structured like this:

file_A

| Task | Duration |
| --- | --- |
| Task1 | 10:00 |
| Task2 | 20:00 |

file_B

| Task | Duration |
| --- | --- |
| Task1 | 30:00 |
| Task2 | 40:00 |

Currently i'm able to take all of these files, group the tasks to new tasks (because there might be typos), aggregate the durations into a new pandas df and export them to an excel file:

current_export_File

| Task | Duration |
| --- | --- |
| Task1 | 40:00 |
| Task2 | 60:00 |

I'm looking for a way to create a new column for every excel file in the folder which is named after a specific part of the file name:

wanted_export_File

| Task | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Task1 | 10:00 | 30:00 |
| Task2 | 20:00 | 40:00 |

I already created a list of the file names part which i want to use as column heading but i'm unsure whether i should create new df for every excel file in the folder to concatenate them afterwards or if there is another way to go. Apart from that i can't figure out how to create a seperate df for every file in the folder.

- Tried to create df for every file in the folder but failed.
- Created working script that just adds up all the task values and aggregates "likely spelled" tasks

Comment: Why did you delete your new question? I had a solution

Comment: Hey thanks for your response, i was trying to edit my question because i put a mistake in it but wasn't able to edit. Now i'm not able to repost the edited question for another 90 minutes...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of dataframes:

```
ids = ['A', 'B']
dfs = [df1, df2]
out = pd.concat({k: d.set_index('Task')['Duration'] for k,d in zip(ids, dfs)},
                axis=1).reset_index()
out.to_excel(...)
```

output:

```
    Task       A      B
0  Task1   10:00  30:00
1  Task2   20:00  40:00
```

For a list of file names:

```
ids = ['A', 'B']
out = pd.concat({k: pd.read_excel(f'file_{k}').set_index('Task') for k in ids},
                 axis=1).reset_index()
out.to_excel(...)
```

Comment: Thanks, solution for list of df's looks exactly like what i need. Problem is i can't figure out how to create a list of df's from files in the directory.

Comment: @faulehenne    ```all_excel_files = [pandas.read_excel(os.path.join('path/to/your/folder', file)) for file in os.listdir('path/to/your/folder')]```